# Spring Prototype scoped bean. Do I need to make fields in it as threadLocal?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, prototype, synchronized

There is a rule of thumb in Spring Framework - Declare stateless beans as singleton and stateful as prototype. However there is no information regarding stateful fields in prototype scoped bean nor the information whether should lookup method be synchronized in order to avoid race conditions?

Let's say I have a stateful bean with several fields

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype") 
class PostOperator {

  @Autowired
  private MailSender mailSender;

  private String lastName;
  private String streetAddress;
  private Long operatorId;
  private Map <String, String> subjectArticle map;


  public PostOperator(String lastName, String streetAddress,  Long operatorId, 
                      Map <String, String> subjectArticle map){
   ...... 
  }

  public void submitEmail(){
     mailSender.send(lastName, streetAddress, operatorId);
  }

}
```

I have a Rest Controller with the Lookup method

```
@RestController
class AppointmentController {
    @GetMapping("/submit")
    public ResponseEntity submit() {
    
    PostOperator operator = getOperator("Smith", "Fleet Str.", 7L, 
                                         new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

    operator.submitEmail();
    return ResponseEntity.ok();
}

@Lookup
public PostOperator getOperator(String lastName, String streetAddress,  Long operatorId,
                                 Map <String, String> subjectArticle map) {
    return null;

}
```

- Do I need to declare fields as ThreadLocal ?
- Do I need to make lookup method synchronized since AFAIK Singleton is not thread safe ?
- Do I need to synchronize submitEmail() method in PostOperator ?

Many thanks Guys for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, as far as the dependent instances does not hold any state that does affect.

In the above example your service `PostOperator` depends on the `MailSender` and it's only responsibility is to send email based on the given parameters where all the behavior is bound to `send` method the only exception is the email configuration.So, in this case based on the email credentials being used `send` method does not rely on the any other state to send method and it also doesn't have any side effects you don't have to worry about thread safety.

Stateless services works find most of the cases with thread safety.

Comment: Agree regarding stateless services, but my concern is that AppointmentController depends on PostOperator which is stateful. Does it make sense to make @Lookup method synchronized in this case? Since lookup method receives arguments and passes to constructor of PostOperator ? Is it possible so that incoming requests can cause a race conditions in this case?

Comment: Since you have annonated `PostOperator` service as `prototype` then this service should be initialised in every request which means new instance of every request and I also don't see the injection of this service into your controller. if the state of service is not going to shared among the request then we don't need to worry and another thing is it does not have side effect like updating the state or modifying then we don't need to worry other wise better to have `syncronized`

Comment: Hi @msucil, PostOperator indeed is not injected into controller, but it is obtained from Lookup method getOperator so it is a local field. Please take a look into controller - there is a line of code: PostOperator operator = getOperator("Smith", "Fleet Str.", 7L, 
                                         new ConcurrentHashMap<>()) right in submit method. At first I'm getting PostOperator instance in the method and then I submit emails.

Comment: in this case whenever `getOperator` is called it returns the new instance of `PostOperator` in that case no need to worry about thread safety because the execution context is bounded to the `getOperator` method.